# Flutter - A RenderFlex overflowed by 572 pixels on the bottom

Tags: listview, flutter, widget

Olá, venho tido alguns erros com Flutter quando se trata na questão de OVERFLOW das bordas.
Fiz uma ListView.builder e ele vem dando overflow na vertical.

O que eu tentei e não funcionou:

Dar Wrap nas 'children' com Flex, Flexible e Expanded.

Também tentei com SingleChildScrollView com a propriedade scrollable: Axis.vertical e mesmo assim não funcionou.

A minha pergunta é **Como fazer o flutter identificar essa lista como SCROLLABLE? Isso já não era para estar acontecendo, devido ao ListView.builder?**
Meu erro é o seguinte:

````
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15581): The following assertion was thrown during layout:
I/flutter (15581): A RenderFlex overflowed by 572 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter (15581):
I/flutter (15581): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (15581):   Column
I/flutter (15581):   file:///C:/Users/vinca/Documents/Flutter%20projects/StarChat/synjolt_rastreio/synjolt_rastreio/lib/results_page.dart:150:16
I/flutter (15581):
I/flutter (15581): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter (15581): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter (15581): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter (15581): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter (15581): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter (15581): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter (15581): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter (15581): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter (15581): like a ListView.
I/flutter (15581): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#dda8e relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter (15581):   needs compositing
I/flutter (15581):   creator: Column ← Center ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
I/flutter (15581):     CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter (15581):     _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#47cf2 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ←
I/flutter (15581):     PhysicalModel ← ⋯
I/flutter (15581):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter (15581):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=653.7)
I/flutter (15581):   size: Size(360.0, 653.7)
I/flutter (15581):   direction: vertical
I/flutter (15581):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter (15581):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter (15581):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter (15581):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter (15581): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤```
````

**Aqui vem o trecho de código do body, que é de onde vem o overflow.**

```
 body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FutureBuilder<Pacote>(
                    future: fetchPacote(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData)
                        return (Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Código de Rastreio: ' + snapshot.data.codigo),
                            Text('Serviço: ' + snapshot.data.servico),
                            Text('Host: ' + snapshot.data.host),
                            Text('Quantidade: ' +
                                snapshot.data.quantidade.toString()),
                            ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.eventos.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                        'Texto é um conjunto de palavras e frases encadeadas que permitem interpretação e transmitem uma mensagem. É qualquer obra escrita em versão original e que constitui um livro ou um documento escrito. Um texto é uma unidade linguística de extensão superior à frase.' +
                                            snapshot
                                                .data.eventos[index].status),
                                  );
                                })
                          ],
                        ));
                      else if (snapshot.hasError)
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");

                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Olá, minha resposta lhe ajudou? Conseguiu resolver seu problema de outra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei a forma que está querendo montar o layout da sua tela, mas tentei dar uma ajeitada na sua árvore de Widgets para tirar algumas redundâncias.

*Caso eu tenha mudado muito a estrutura, mantenha a sua e utilize apenas a parte explicada na secção **Explicação**.*

```
Center(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<Container>(
            future: fetchPacote(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData)
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 250,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Código de Rastreio: ' +
                              snapshot.data.codigo),
                          Text('Serviço: ' + snapshot.data.servico),
                          Text('Host: ' + snapshot.data.host),
                          Text('Quantidade: ' +
                              snapshot.data.quantidade.toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.eventos.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                  'Texto é um conjunto de palavras e frases encadeadas que permitem interpretação e transmitem uma mensagem. É qualquer obra escrita em versão original e que constitui um livro ou um documento escrito. Um texto é uma unidade linguística de extensão superior à frase.' +
                                      snapshot.data.eventos[index].status),
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              else if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");

              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**Explicação**

Coloquei um `Container` que irá conter um `Column` com os textos informativos que necessita, fiz isso pois no caso do seu layout, você precisa por sua `ListView` dentro de um Widget chamado `Expanded` que é quem vai tratar o tamanho da sua lista dentro do espaço disponível... E para que tudo se encaixe, os componentes que não possuem o `Expanded` precisam ter tamanhos fixos.

Ficando assim seu layout dividido em duas partes

> **Cabeçalho:**
>   Container de tamanho 250 possuindo as informações "Código", "Serviço"...
>
> **Corpo:**
>   Lista com tamanho flexível, que vai ficar do tamanho que sobrar em tela.